# Safari and fetch()

Tags: javascript, safari, fetch

I've found old articles on fetch() on Safari.  But in 2019 I go to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch) and it states that fetch is supported.  I'm using Safari version: 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1) but it seems that fetch is always undefined whether I use it as window.fetch() or fetch():

```
            let params = {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                }
            }

            const queryData = {
                query: query,
                variables: query_variables
            };


            params.body = JSON.stringify(queryData);
            const response = await fetch(url, params);
```

I know there is a fetch polyfill https://github.com/github/fetch but I would like to avoid using it since its suppose to be supported already.  A
I see that the release was back in 10.1 so I would expected it to work.  Any ideas what could be causing this?  I dont have a problem with Chrome, Firefox and even Edge

**Update 1**
My original code was using the function fetch() only without window.fetch().  I just added to see if it worked.  When debugging in Safari, watching fetch() as a watch expression gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't perhaps have a variable declared named `fetch` would you?

Comment: Open your Developers Tools, go to console, and type `fetch` - if it evaluates to a function, then you're doing something in your code to hide it. And btw, you do not need `window.fetch` - `fetch` should work.

Comment: @SterlingArcher  He's using `window.fetch`, and he also say's working in Chrome, Firefox & Edge.

Comment: @Keith I'm just exploring potential options. However, setting `fetch` (without `window.`) would still overwrite the global window property

Comment: Originally my code was just fetch without window.  I just added window.fetch() to try it out.  But if I just leave it to fetch and debug in Safari its not defined at all.  On chrome its defined

Comment: Here is my output with Safari fetch(): fetch: function()

arguments: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.

caller: TypeError: 'arguments', 'callee', and 'caller' cannot be accessed in this context.

length: 1

name: "fetch"

Comment: The problem isnt in the fetch, the problem is in the POST. Safari for some reason isnt happy with method POST in fetch.